# querying the rows with a condition on another row in a certain group in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table with three columns: `segment_num`, `pass_num`, `is_done`. `pass_num` is a set of (0,1). For each `segment_num` there are the set of all the `pass_nums` (two times), which means that there are 4 rows for each `segment_num`. `is_done` can be true or false.

```
segment_num   pass_num   is_done
 1000         0          True
 1000         1                
 1000         0          True   
 1000         1          
     
 1001         0          True
 1001         1              
 1001         0          False
 1001         1          
   
 1002         0          False
 1002         1                
 1002         0          False
 1002         1
```

For simplicity, I did not fill the `is_done` fields for the rows that do not matter. I want to query all the `segment_num`s that at least have one is_done=True for pass_num 0.

So in this example, 1000 and 1001 have at least one (pass_num=0 and is_done=True).
So the result should be 1000 and 1001.

I think I should use group_by for each segment_num and in each group I should decide whether to keep the segment_num or ignore it based on the is_done value for pass_num=0 in it.
I would prefer to write this in Sqlalchemy ORM. Any help would be really appreciated.

So far I have this:

```
db.session.query(Mytable).group_by(Mytable.segment_num).all()
```

I am not sure how to add the condition to the group_by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample SQL in MySQL would be:

```
select segment_num from mytable where pass_num=0 and is_done=True group by 
segment_num;
```

So to do it in SQLAlchemy

Import **and_**:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_
```

And then get the result:

```
segments = db.session.query(MyTable.segment_num)
             .filter(and_(MyTable.pass_num == 0,
                          MyTable.is_done == True))
             .group_by(MyTable.segment_num).all()
```

which will give you values for single column *segment_num* grouped by values.